# how to update nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, blender

Suddenly in blender i noticed CUDA could not be enabled. It says I have no cuda compatible cards. It was working fine until recently so i decided to see if I could find out if the driver is working OK. I have a titan x with proprietry nvidia drivers. It says the drivers are manually installed but I never did that and now im not sure how to update them in ubuntu.

can anyone please help?

Many thanks

Comment: You update the Nvidia driver the same way you update everything else, using apt or the GUI package manager. It should already be the current version unless you are neglecting proper system maintenance. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  You're asking how to update a driver but that's not the real problem you are experiencing and it's probably not going to solve your actual problem. You should instead search/research/ask about the actual problem that you are facing-- the problem you are having in blender.

Comment: We don't know your OS & release details; given that I'll suggest `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` given no other details were provided.

Answer (score -1):

done it.

Nmath > was not a blender issue so no use asking after i identified it was driver issue but i got it now thanks
guiverc > yes sorry, was late when i posted so i missed important details.

I just needed to purge nvidia data and reinstall.